# Issue with MacOS script for opening application and clicking button if another app opens

Tags: applescript

I'm receiving the following error when trying to run my script, although I suspect there might be other issues than this immediate error. "system Events got an error: Can't get process "logitune".

I'm tryingto open LogiTune and click the first item under "my devices" *if* Zoom (app) is opened. Here is my script:

[My apple script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wjXgb.png)

And here is the LogiTune interface that I'm trying to manipulate:
[LogiTune interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nr5hP.png)

Comment: To check if an app is running you will need to use something like `application "zoom.us" is running` instead of that `open` command.

Comment: Now that I think of it, is using apple script the best way to achieve my goal? I want to run a script when zoom opens in any way, so something would always need to be listening for zoom to open, and *then* run the script to open logitune.

Comment: AppleScriptObjC is handy because you are already using AppleScript to control other applications, but you can use anything else that is able to use the Cocoa API to register for and observe NSWorkspace notifications, such as Swift, Objective-C, PyObjc, etc.